# AWS Elastic Search With Kibana - Authentication through IP-based policies or resource-based policies DO NOT WORK AT ALL

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cognito

at my serverless.yaml file I create and restrict the access to my ElasticSearch domain service and Kibana. However, through AWS Resource-based policies or AWS IP-based policies I am not able to access kibana.
The restriction was done following the AWS Tutorial Source below
For example:

[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html#es-ac-types-ip)

However, it does not worked and I got the error when I tried to access Kibana: {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}

So, it means that Kibana requires recently an user. So, the only way now is to use AWS Cognito??

Thank you very much in advance!
Cheers,
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your access policy as

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:****:domain/es-cert/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "88.8.888.8"           
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the `"aws:SourceIp"` section, you need to add your public IP address

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have done this anyway! This is also highlighted in the document of amazon linked above. But I got the error above anyway: {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}

Comment: @Turtles That's strange, have you added your own public IP Address under `"aws:SourceIp"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would question which ElasticSearch domain you created.  Did you create it with VPC or HTTP access?  I did just this the other day and in trying to implement my IP access policy, nothing worked.  I finally found this article, recreated my domain, applied my access policy, similar to what you have above, and it worked.

“If you enabled VPC access, you can't use IP-based policies. Instead, you can use security groups to control which IP addresses can access the domain.”

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/createupdatedomains.html